# how to add correctly script.js to html with node ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So im totally green with node. I had base web with index.html and script.js file. It was working correctly, but now i have added node.js and file app.js which is runing it. After that my script.js is not loading to html correctly. All files except styles.css are in the same directory, however styles are loading correctly to html.

Throwed error:
GET http://localhost:3000/script.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="styles/styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

script.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    document.getElementById('sampleeditor').setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
});

function format(command, value) {
    document.execCommand(command, false, value);
}
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path')

const app = express()

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
})

app.listen(port)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't configure express to serve static files
Please see the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) about how to do it.
Here's an example from the doc

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.static('files'))
```